# Error in converting Excel data to CSV using C# code

Tags: c#, excel, csv, c#-3.0, converters

I am using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536181/is-there-any-simple-way-to-convert-xls-file-to-csv-file-excel) to convert Excel data to CSV.

```
   static void ConvertExcelToCsv(string excelFilePath, string csvOutputFile, int worksheetNumber = 1) 
    {
   var cnnStr = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO\"", excelFilePath);
   var cnn = new OleDbConnection(cnnStr);
   var dt = new DataTable();
  try {
  cnn.Open();
       }   
     }
```

I am getting the following exception once the `cnn.open()` line gets executed:

> "External table is not in expected format"

Comment: This code is trying to connect specifically to an Excel 8.0 spreadsheet. What format is the spreadsheet you're connecting to in?

Comment: i am trying to convert excel 2010 to csv

Comment: You need to change `Excel 8.0` to `Excel 14.0` in your `cnnStr`. Note if you're loading an `xlsx` rather than a `xls` file you'll need `Excel 14.0 Xml` instead.

Comment: When i changed the cnnStr with Excel 14.0 - it says Excel 14.0 is not registered on local machine

Comment: You'll need to install [this package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734). I know it says it's for Office 2007, but it covers 2010 as well.

Answer (score 0):

The question in the link is old and using Excel 8.0 Spreadsheet version as Octopoid stated. You can try with the version 12.0 or figure out which version you use :

```
var cnnStr = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};" + "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'");
```

If you can't manage to make it work, you can always use a library :>

Library is called "excellibrary" 
Here is the link : https://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/

It is pretty simple to use it. It has a Wiki in the given link so you can get familiar with the usage.

Oğuzhan

Answer (score -1):

Heyho,
you can open the .xls file and save it as .csv with C#