# Azure Data Lake Excel Export To CSV as Same Folder / Path

Tags: excel, database, azure, csv, ssis

have you ever made an azure data convert **Azure Data Lake excel** conversion to **CSV** file.

first, I have tried using SSIS with Azure Data Lake Source, but when Mapping is not possible, the choice is to add text.

second, says try using **azure apps logic** with **create CSV table** but the csv that comes out is only the structure in that folder

Thank you in advance

Comment: Check this  -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536181/is-there-any-simple-way-to-convert-xls-file-to-csv-file-excel

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926710/converting-xlsx-file-using-to-a-csv-file

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31316551/convert-excel-file-xls-or-xlsx-to-csv-file

Comment: Hi Oki Kuswanda, If my answer is helpful for you, please mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a built-in way to extract from excel file in Azure data lake. I would suggest you to try one of the below approaches:

- Write Custom .NET library for converting Excel to CSV and deploy that to Azure Data Lake Analytics. [Azure Data Lake Analytics Programming Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-u-sql-programmability-guide)
- Write a custom .NET activity in Azure Data Factory to do this. [Custom Activities in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity)
- Use Azure Functions and Open XML do this activity as detailed in the [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43171845/download-an-excel-file-and-read-content-with-azure-functions/43228473#43228473)
- Use SSIS Package to do the conversion. You can have SSIS Runtimes in Azure Data Factory. [SSIS packages running in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-invoke-ssis-package-ssis-activity)

Answer (score 0):

As I know about Azure, These isn't any way can help convert the excel file to csv directly.

You could follow these steps:

1. Download the excel file to you computer.
2. Import the excel file to the you SQL database.
3. Then export the table data as CSV file to you Blob Storage.

You could reference this document:

1. [Import data from Excel to SQL Server or Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#prereq)
2. [Connect to Azure Blob Storage (SQL Server Import and Export
   Wizard)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/connect-to-azure-blob-storage-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15)

Hope this helps.