# SSIS process for saving .xlsx file as .csv file

Tags: sql-server, excel, csv, ssis, etl

I am trying to download a .xlsx excel file from FTP server and save it in a .csv file format.
I was able to download a file from server using ftp task in SSIS and save it in a local folder now I want to save that file as csv file format for import process. I could not find a conversion method or task from .xlxs to csv. i tried script task but it didn't work. can someone please help.

Comment: Please be more specific - what did you do in your script task, and what happened?  "It didn't work" isn't much to go on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a Script task to achieve this, and inside the script you can use Interop Library:

- [Converting XLSX file using to a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926710/converting-xlsx-file-using-to-a-csv-file)
- [Convert .xlsx & .xls to .csv](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/246772/Convert-xlsx-xls-to-csv)
- [How to Convert Excel to CSV using Interop](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/683804/How-to-Convert-Excel-to-CSV-using-Interop)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do that will be to use an Excel source and a Flat File Destination (set it as a CSV). Hope it helps.

Comment: SSIS Excel source doesnt accept .xlsx  file format so cant do that

Comment: It does support. For your quick reference: https://dataintegrity.wordpress.com/2009/10/16/xlsx/

Comment: @tanay which version of ssis you are using?

Comment: hi i am using sql server data tool 14.0.61712.050 and its not working as i can not see the option for choosing odbc 12.o driver.i can see the jet driver but not MS office 12.0 odbc driver as shown in the exaple @deepak lakhotia provided.

Comment: I'm not sure this will help with the most used case for this question. Excel misinterpreting data types.