# How to read files with .xlsx and .xls extension in Azure data factory?

Tags: excel, azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to read and excel file in Azure Blob Storage with .xlsx extension in my azure data factory dataset. it throws following error

```
Error found when processing 'Csv/Tsv Format Text' source 'Filename.xlsx' with row number 3: found more columns than expected column count: 1.
```

What are the right Column and row delimiters for excel files to be read in azure Data factory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Data Factory V2 has recently released an update to support parsing Excel(.xls) files on existing connectors.

Currently, the connections supporting excel files are:

- Amazon S3
- Azure Blob
- Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1
- Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2
- Azure File Storage
- File System
- FTP
- Google Cloud Storage
- HDFS
- HTTP
- SFTP

More details can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-excel

Answer (score 8):

**Update March 2022:**  ADF now has better support for Excel via Mapping Data Flows:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-excel

Excel files have a proprietary format and are not simple delimited files.  As indicated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=sql-server-2017#adf), Azure Data Factory does **not** have a direct option to import Excel files, eg you **cannot** create a Linked Service to an Excel file and read it easily.  Your options are:

1. Export or convert the data as flat files eg before transfer to cloud, as .csv, tab-delimited, pipe-delimited etc are easier to read than Excel files.  This is your simplest option although obviously requires a change in process.
2. Try shredding the XML - create a custom task to open the Excel file as XML and extract your data as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109957/loading-data-from-excel-file-into-azure-datawarehouse).
3. SSIS packages are now supported in Azure Data Factory (with the [Execute SSIS package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-invoke-ssis-package-ssis-activity) activity) and have better support for Excel files, eg a Connection Manager.   So it *may* be an option to create an SSIS package to deal with the Excel and host it in ADFv2.  **Warning!**  I have not tested this, I am only speculating it is possible.  Also there is the overhead of creating an Integration Runtime (IR) for running SSIS in ADFv2.
4. <s>Try some other custom activity, eg there is a custom U-SQL Extractor for shredding XML on github [here](https://github.com/Azure/AzureDataLake/tree/master/Samples/ExcelExtractor).</s>
5. Try and read the Excel using Databricks, some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44196741/how-to-construct-dataframe-from-a-excel-xls-xlsx-file-in-scala-spark) although spinning up a Spark cluster to read a few Excel files does seem somewhat overkill.  This might be a good option if Spark is already in your architecture.

Let us know how you get on.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Factory does not have a direct option to upload the excel, however, it can be uploaded **through linked service** via some configurations. Follow below steps to do so:

1. Create a Linked service to the source using the appropriate protocol(FTP, Fileshare, SFTP etc.)
2. Create a Linked Service to your cloud storage.
3. Take a **Copy Data** activity, define a filesystem Source Dataset and Sink using your previously defined linked services
4. In Source and Sink, tick the Binary file option.[Binary file option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJbod.png)
5. Publish and execute your pipeline

Answer (score 0):

I would like to elaborate a bit more on option 3. SSIS packages. I tested the solution and it sorta worked. First of all - SSIS IR is super expensive and You would like to use [http post's to start-stop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-schedule-azure-ssis-integration-runtime) it while it is not needed.

Secondly, SSIS does not support processing blob files out of the box. There are some ways around it. You can use some third-party soft (didn't try that), or [explore options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lift-shift/ssis-azure-files-file-shares?view=sql-server-ver15)

In my case I used trick to deploy package that download file locally, process and then delete it. Since SSIS IR is a VM, it basically did the same on IR after deployment. It was a trick rather than solution and it was not 100% stable. Another issue - numeric fields got some insignificant error during processing - eg. uploading 25 resulted in 25.0000000001 at db site. No idea why. I did not have enough time to investigate issues deeper.

Comment: Doesn't the [Azure Feature Pack for Integration Services (SSIS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/azure-feature-pack-for-integration-services-ssis?view=sql-server-ver15) work with Azure Blob Store?