# In Azure Data Factory read excel files

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am new to Azure Data Factory(ADF), I need to access/load excel files sitting in a blob into ADF but as ADF doesn't support excel format(supports tex/csv/json/.. only) is there a way to ingest excel files into ADF?
I really appreciate if anybody could help!

Thanks.

Comment: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/19807720-add-excel-as-source to share the need for this with the ADF team

Comment: @Mhansma just did!

Comment: Microsoft is working on adding Excel as a data source for ADF. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/19807720-add-excel-as-source?tracking_code=b40710f566523bae82d8585edf5aee4c

Answer (score 5):

ADF does not support reading from xls file yet.

You can find solutions in this answer: [How to read files with .xlsx and .xls extension in Azure data factory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52514153/how-to-read-files-with-xlsx-and-xls-extension-in-azure-data-factory)

Comment: Thanks for the referral @BoXiao : )  How about an upvote please?  : )

Comment: Yes I have gone through these earlier may be at last should adopt any of the mentioned options. I was looking for any simple straight forward approach. Anyways appreciate your reply! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

ADF V2 now supports reading data from an Excel file, [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-excel?WT.mc_id=linkedin) is the link to the article.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

ADF now support Excel as a data source. You can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-excel)

Answer (score 1):

You are right, Azure Data Factory does not support to read `.xlsx` file, the workaround is to save your `.xlsx` file as a `.csv` file, I think it should work.

My `.xlsx` file:

[image]

Save as `.csv` file, the info will not change:

[image]

Preview Data in ADF:

[image]

**Besides**, if you want to just copy the `.xlsx` file, no need to convert it to `.csv`, you just need to choose the `Binary Copy` option.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply, But sadly neither will help in my case. Firstly I need to automate entire process and its recurring. Secondly I need to edit file before copying so binary option won't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with SSIS, you could simply use Excel Source in your SSIS package, and then run it on SSIS Integration Runtime using Execute SSIS Package activity in ADF pipeline.

Comment: I am a beginner in this regard, Will appreciate you can point out to any document which has clear description for the same.

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution is to use a powerautomate flow to export an excel table as a CSV and trigger the datafactory process. The only issue is that an undocumented feature on power automate is  that you need to use a fixed Excel file name as passing the name as a variable fails.