# How to convert excel file to csv in azure data factory

Tags: excel, azure, csv, azure-data-factory

Hi I'm looking for some help here. I am new to Azure Data Factory and I need to convert some Excel files to csv, how can I do this?

Comment: There is no direct support of Excel in ADF.  Please see below for more details.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52514153/how-to-read-files-with-xlsx-and-xls-extension-in-azure-data-factory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i know,Excel file is not supported by ADF so far,only [these formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs) are supported.

So,you could try some workarounds to process excel files in ADF:

1.Use Databricks Activity to load excel files and convert into csv files,please refer to this case:[How to construct Dataframe from a Excel (xls,xlsx) file in Scala Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44196741/how-to-construct-dataframe-from-a-excel-xls-xlsx-file-in-scala-spark)

2.Use Azure Function Activity to convert excel files into csv files,you could choose development language to implement that. Then output the csv files into specific path and use them in the next steps.

3.Try Custom Activity which is actually tasks(for example,execute a Powershell Script) running on the Azure Batch Node.This approach is more flexible and easy to operate.

Answer (score 3):

As of **2022** `.xlsx` and `.xls` [files are supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-excel) as source but not as sink.

This means that we can use a `copy` activity in Azure Synapse / Azure Data Factory to extract the data from a specific sheet of the `xlsx` file (=source) and copy it to a `csv` file (=sink).