# How to parse .xls file line by line using C#?

Tags: c#

How to parse .xls file line by line using C#? Or it is possible to convert from .xls to .csv file using C#?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5QCp8zWvdyLQllmRk9GOHlNM2c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The answer to this question is just a Google search away, there are a host of libraries that allow you to read XLS files even without Excel installed. You can also set up an OleDb connection and query the spreadsheet like you would query any other database.

Answer (score 1):

You can read them like a matrix, consisting of rows and columns. There are lots of libraries on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=xls) to do that. Or you can look at the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536181/is-there-any-simple-way-to-convert-xls-file-to-csv-file-excel) to convert it to a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft Excel Interop Assemblies to read the excel files .