# Import Data from a xls file to datagridview?

Tags: c#, import, datagridview, xls

I want to Import data from a xls file into my datagridview, but I Keep getting the error: Input Array is bigger than the number of columns. How can I solve it? I get the error in this line: _table.Rows.Add(data_col);

Here is my Code:

```
private void OpenXlsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ExcelÖffnen = new OpenFileDialog()
        {
            Title = "Open Excel Files",
            CheckPathExists = true,
            DefaultExt = "txt",
            Filter = "Excel files (*.xls)|*.xls",
            FilterIndex = 1,
            RestoreDirectory = true
        };

        if (ExcelÖffnen.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string[] raw_txt = File.ReadAllLines(ExcelÖffnen.FileName);
            string[] data_col = null;
            int x = 0;

            foreach (string txt_line in raw_txt)
            {
            
                string[] vs = txt_line.Split(';');
                data_col = vs;
                

                if (x == 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= data_col.Count() - 1; i++)
                    {
                        _table.Columns.Add(data_col[i]);
                    }

                    x++;
                }
                else
                {
                    _table.Rows.Add(data_col);
                }
            }
           
        }
```

Any help would be nice :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: `xls` is a binary file (perhaps you want to use csv or convert xls into csv first?). You can't use `ReadAllLines` to read it, nor split text by using `;` to get items, rather you need a library. You are geting error because first line (which you use to generate columns) has less items than some other line.

Comment: do you know How I could convert it to a csv?

Comment: Open xls in excel and save as (export?) to csv. Or you want to [convert it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2536181/1997232) programmatically? Btw, parsing csv is also not that trivial task, you may still need to use library for that.

Comment: I told you last time you asked this question you need a library to read excel files, they are not simple text.

Comment: As commented already, you will need an Excel library to read the Excel files in your code. To help you decide which library to use, you need to take stock of “where” this code going to be run and if you are willing to “pay” for the library. I suggest you read all of the answers and comments from @Sinatr first link. There are many factors that need to be considered before you choose a particular library.

Comment: One is that if this code is going to be promoted into a production environment, then, you need to check with the server manager and see if they will allow you to add the library to the server’s environment. It is rare that this would be allowed and, in most cases, it will NOT be allowed. If this is for your own use on your own machine, then I say pick your own poison.

Comment: If Office is installed on your machine, then, Interop is an obvious choice. However, it has some drawbacks. Example; if you upgrade your Office application, then you may/will also need to re-factor and recompile this code since the library has changed. When you use a third-party library, then, the Office upgrade usually has no affect of the code you have, however there is no guarantee of this as certain libraries only work with certain versions of Excel workbooks.

Comment: I have used Interop and third-party libraries in the past, and you should be aware that one of the reasons you even see these third-party libraries is because Interop is notoriously slow, particularly with large files, among other issues. There are ways to get around Interop’s sluggishness, however this will usually involve doing things in unconventional ways. There are numerous free third-party options and it would be an “opinion” as to which one is the best. I have found EPPLus/OpenXML to be a good substitute. Pick a library and test it out. Good Luck.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I got it to work not so that it even Shows the data from the Excel file. I used the Office library and now it seems to work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to work with office interop libaries.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/how-to-access-office-onterop-objects